# SQL Where condition in group by with 2 contradicting clauses

Tags: sql

I have a Table like so:

```
ID1|ID2|ID3|Enabled
1   1   0   1
1   1   1   1
1   1   2   1
2   1   1   1
2   1   2   1
2   1   3   1
3   1   0   0
3   1   1   1   
3   1   2   1
4   1   0   1  
4   1   0   1   
4   1   0   1
```

I want to group by first `ID1` then `ID2` and select all `ID1` where within each group, `ID3` contains both 0 (If Enabled column is 1) and nonzero value.  So the table provided will return -

```
ID1
1
```

```
SELECT ID1 From Table1
GROUP BY ID1, ID2
WHERE
???
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What do you mean "within each group"?  You have defined two different levels of aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `having` clause, if your definition of group is based on `ID1`/`ID2`:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID1, ID2
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ID3 = 0 AND Enabled = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN ID3 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a group by with an alternative having as you would not be able to use having for id3 as id3 should be present in group by first to be used in having else ypu can use only aggregates in having. So, In order to make the id3 case work I have used here `case when` which is checking id3 if found as either 0 or 1 would be returning value as 1 in each such case. Therefore, the sum on top of case act as an aggregate in having hence would work as if sum obtained based on the cases comes as greater than or equal to 2  or more(if duplicates of 0 and 1) then output those rows of that partcular group.

```
select ID1 
from Table1 
where enabled = 1 
group by ID1, ID2
having sum( case when ID3 in (1,0) then 
1 else 0 end) >= 2
```

Comment: If you would have added an explanation along with your query example, it would have been more appreciated.